# How can I load local html pages into unity?

Tags: unity

How can I open an HTML page inside UNITY, with the page functioning normally?

Comment: Use the WWW.Load () feature. More info here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/517414/how-to-use-www-to-load-local-files.html You'll need to know the file path on the users device.

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Unity doesn't have a built-in browser widget, but [this web browser library](https://developer.vuplex.com/webview/overview) is good for embedding web pages in your game. We use it on Windows and mobile.

Comment: Unity does not have any built-in solution afaik. However, this open-source plugin works great to load a WebView inside unity. Looks like it's updated regularly as well. https://github.com/gree/unity-webview

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "the page functioning normally". Assuming you mean a browseable webpage within a game, then no.

You can make HTTP requests from Unity and thus download the data, but Unity isn't a web browser and won't display the HTML as a webpage. Similarly, Unity can open a web browser to a specific URL, but then that's not "inside Unity".

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial to load information and files from a url online into unity by passing json, xml, material types (unity doesnt have a browser itself). Alteratively, you can pass the user to their browser to view the webpage.